# RISCV and Spike: Add something and read value

Tags: gcc, assembly, addition, riscv, spike

I want to write a simple RISCV program in assembly and then test it. The program should simply load a value into a register and add a value to it:

```
    .file   "hello.c"
.text
.align  2
.globl  main
.type   main, @function
main:
   li  a0, 2
   add a0, a0, 7

  .size main, .-main
  .ident    "GCC: (GNU) 5.3.
```

However, when I type in:

> riscv64-unknown-elf-gcc hello.s
>
> spke -d pk a.out
>
> reg 0 a0

It always returns 0x0000000000000000. Why? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is it normal that there's no return instruction at the end of `main`?  Doesn't execution just fall into the next function?  (which might zero a0 and exit the process if you're lucky).  I'm not familiar with RISCV or the simulator you're using, but I'm guessing that `reg 0 a0` is debug output from the simulator, and the previous two lines are shell commands?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you start spike with -d, the command prompt is printed before any instructions are executed.

Disassemble your compiled program to see all the instructions wrapped around your two instruction main() subroutine.

```
riscv64-unknown-elf-objdump -d hello | less
Disassembly of section .text:

0000000000010000 <_ftext>:
   10000:       00002197                auipc   gp,0x2

...
0000000000010164 <main>:
   10164:       00200513                li      a0,2
   10168:       00750513                addi    a0,a0,7
```

I told spike to run to the first instruction of main, then single stepped, and then displayed register a0:

```
$ spike -d pk foo

Note: Hitting enter is the same as: run 1
: until pc 0 0x0000000000010164
: pc 0
0x0000000000010164
: run 1
core   0: 0x0000000000010164 (0x00200513) li      a0, 2
: reg 0 a0
0x0000000000000002
: run 1
core   0: 0x0000000000010168 (0x00750513) addi    a0, a0, 7
: reg 0 a0
0x0000000000000009
```

As commenter Peter points out, a procedure usually returns at the end. In the case of main, it falls through to atexit(), etc.

You can use the "r" command to see the complete execution trace of "pk hello".

Comment: Thank you so much for this answer. This helped me a lot. Also, I found out that it is possible to type e.g. "run 10" and 10 commands will be executed - is there any command to execute whole program?

Comment: "run" with no arguments will run and display all instructions.